# Can I use class types defined in c++ static library in swift

Tags: c++, ios, swift, xcode

I have a static C++ library that I want to use in swift.
I found that I must make a ObjC++ wrapper to be able to call that code in swift.

What I'm thinking about is whether it is possible to make new instances of classes defined in the C++ library directly in swift, or is it possible to expose return types and params from the library in the wrapper file? or should I make like a mapping classes in the Wrapper file to match every C++ type that I need to use, which is tedious operation.

Comment: You can use [Scapix Language Bridge](https://github.com/scapix-com/scapix) to call C++ from Swift. Disclaimer: I am the author of [Scapix Language Bridge](https://github.com/scapix-com/scapix).

Answer (score 1):

From the [Apple developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/29527):

> Unfortunately, C++ interoperability is not considered in the current (and near future) Swift. See the README.md in the [swift-evolution GitHub repository](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution).
>
> You need to write C-function based interfacing wrappers in C++, or Objective-C class based wrappers in Objective-C++.

That was posted a while ago, but I don't think anything has changed.